# My I-94 travel history is no longer accessible. What could be the reason?

Tags: usa, i-94

I am a foreign resident in the US on a visa.

Recently, I found out that my I-94 travel history is no longer available from the DHS website. The I-94 itself is still accessible but it claims that 'no record found' in my case.

I am wondering what could be reason. The passport is the same. In particular, could that be a security measure against unauthorized access?

Comment: Maybe just a glitch on the DHS website, does it have a phone/email contact that you can ask about that ?

Comment: I also get “no record found” so it is not specific to the OP.

Comment: When did you last enter US?

Comment: My wife's records have been like this for the last year or two.  Her most recent I-94 is available, but no history.  She also resides in the US in nonimmigrant status.  @zhantongz she travels outside the US a few times every year, at least once a year, most recently in August 2020.

Comment: Any update ? As for me also the travel history shows no record found for last 5 years which is not true as I have travelled several times. Thanks